# How can I use huge pages and libhugetlbfs on a Debian EC2 PVM instance?

Tags: debian, amazon-ec2, memory, debian-wheezy, linux

On my local machine (i7 9200) running Debian Wheezy amd64 I can get some significant speedups on some "big data"/HPC type stuff by:

- Following the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages) to reserve some RAM for huge pages and setting up hugetlbfs.
- Running my application using [libhugetlbfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libhugetlbfs/files/)' (2.17) nifty `HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes` to redirect its mallocs to 2M pages.

The application also runs reasonably well on Debian Wheezy on EC2 (I'm using [latest wheezy AMI](https://wiki.debian.org/Cloud/AmazonEC2Image/Wheezy#A7.2)) with normal 4k pages (some scalabilty testing tried on c3.2xlarge, c3.4xlarge and c3.8xlarge instances).  But I'm curious to also see whether I see similar benefits using huge pages on EC2, if it's possible.

I fired up a c3.3xlarge instance and set up huge pages [as usual](https://wiki.debian.org/Hugepages).  And after that  /proc/meminfo does indeed report

```
HugePages_Total:    4096
HugePages_Free:     4095
```

However after compiling libhugetlbfs, it's `make func` self-testing triggers some kernel errors.  The system soon after seems to lock up, but not before I'd had time to inspect dmesg and see a bunch of call stacks with various `xen_` and `hugetlb_fault` symbols in them.  Once it became unresponsive, system needed a forcible stop from the AWS console to get it to halt.

I did try booting up again and just running my app with `HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes` anyway (in case the `make func` testing was breaking on something obscure I didn't actually need), but much the same thing happened again.

Any **success stories with libhugetlbfs on EC2** (preferably with Debian), or **recipes for getting it working correctly** ?

**Research**: there's scant googleable info about huge pages on EC2 (or Xen) out there.  I did find [this](http://www.pythian.com/blog/linux-hugepages-for-oracle-on-amazon-ec2-possible-but-not-convenient-easy-or-fully-supported/), which seems to report the same problem: /proc/meminfo reports hugepages available, but attempting to use them kernel panics.  Article predates the new c3 instances but suggests a cc2.8xlarge might be worth a go due to it using HVM instead of PVM.

**Update**: couldn't find an up-to-date Debian AMI for HVM, but tried an Ubuntu one (13.04 "raring") on a cc2.8xlarge and libhugetlbfs and `HUGETLB_MORECORE=yes` does seem to work fine on that.  The only thing is, it actually slows my application down a little!

Comment: The documentation I've found from Red Hat states: hugepages cannot be used in a paravirtualized XEN guest. RHEL 5 doesn't have this feature enabled. If vm.nr_hugepages is set in RHEL 6 the pages can be allocated, but as soon as they are used the paravirtualized guest will crash. hugepages can be used in a fully virtualized (HVM) XEN guest as well as in a KVM environment.

Comment: Is that basically a limitation of PVM and Xen forever, end of story, or could it in principle be got to work with the right kernel, an up-to-date-enough Xen host/guest or something?